# How should I do with "std::cerr" and "std::cin.fail()" using c++?

Tags: c++

Could you please help me with the small question?

Question:
The program should return an error code(1) and print this exact string in case a failure is encountered:
“Error encountered, exiting...”

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    int number, random;
    random = (std::rand() % 100);

    while (std::cin >> number)
    {
        if (number < random && number >= 0)
        {
            std::cout << "This number is larger." << std::endl;
        }
        else if (number > random && number <= 99)
        {
            std::cout << "This number is smaller." << std::endl;
        }
        else if (std::cin.fail())
        {
            std::cout << "Error encountered, exiting..." << std::endl;
        }
        else if (number < 0 || number > 99)
        {
            std::cout << "[WARNING] : Number must be between 0 and 99" << std::endl;
        }

        else if (number == random)
        {
            std::cout << "Great! You're right!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    };

    return 0;
}
```

After compilation, I will input e.g. 'write'. My programming is directly finished. I don't get 'Error encountered, exiting...' in my terminal.
Could you give some suggestions about `std::cin.fail()`? How should I do?
I also don't understand, could I change here `std::cout` using `std::cerr`? What is the big difference between `std::cout` and `std::cerr`?

Thanks so much

Best regards

Comment: By the way, `std::endl` is a bad habit.

Comment: To finish the comment by @Deduplicator, inserting `'\n'` ends a line without the extra stuff that `std::endl` does.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion. Your suggestion is very useful for me. I will change this bad habit after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should test `std::cin.fail()` *after* the `while` loop because if `std::cin >> number` fails, the body of the `while` loop will not be entered.

You could also restructure the tests a bit to not have to perform the same tests over and over again. Also, `std::endl` flushes the output stream which is unnecessary in the vast majority of cases and just takes extra time.

```
    // ...
    while (std::cin >> number)
    {
        if (number < 0 || number > 99)
        {
            std::cout << "[WARNING] : Number must be between 0 and 99\n";
        }
        else if (number < random) // no need to test if it's out of bounds
        {
            std::cout << "This number is larger.\n";
        }
        else if (number > random) // no need to test if it's out of bounds
        {
            std::cout << "This number is smaller.\n";
        }
        else                       // no need to test anything
        {
            std::cout << "Great! You're right!\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    if(std::cin.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Error encountered, exiting...\n";
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The difference between `std::cout` and `std::cerr` is which output stream it'll use. People running your program can read both streams separately if they want to do logging of errors for example.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.  It runs perfectly. I try to do `std::cout` or `std::cerr` in this code. But it shows me the same output. Does it mean, they don't have a big difference if my programming is not complex.

Comment: @JasonLyu You're welcome! If you use `std::cout << "Hello\n"; std::cerr << "World\n";` and run the program both will show up on the screen since both streams are mapped to your screen device by default. If you run the program with `./program > stdout.txt` (in a shell that uses `>` to redirect the output), the `Hello` will not show on the screen but will instead be put in the file `stdout.txt` while `World` will still show on the screen.